# Ubuntu 13.04 won't download software

Tags: software-center, openvpn

I upgraded Ubuntu version 11 to ver 13.04. When I try to download anything like "openvpn" a message of "Failed to fetch openvpn and 404 File not found" occurs. It also says the software cannot be authenticated.  It seems to be attempting to access Nz.archives.com without success. This happens in Software Center, in the terminal with "apt-get install" and in synaptic package manager. Is a tweak possible or is Ubuntu no longer compatible with this HP-Compaq Desktop? I also have "software Updater" on this machine but it won't work and suggests I "check the internet connection." My connection is great to all three of my machines so what gives?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is compatible with you laptop for sure. Maybe you have problems because 13.10 is not supported anymore https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases Try to install one of LTS, for example Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

When an old release is not supported anymore, package sources are moved from `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. To be able to download any package from the official repositories, you must edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` so that it reflects this change, i.e. replacing any occurence of `archive.ubuntu.com` with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, like so:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main universe restricted multiverse
```